# Объясните, как работают параметры функции JQuery в нижеприведенных примерах

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Как работает этот параметр data? Мы же его не определили перед тем как вызвать функцию, что он делает? Зачем он вообще нужен, он же пустой.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'response.php?action=sample1',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.results').html(data);
  }
});
```

Пересмотрел кучу видео и везде код типа этого

```
function test(a, b) {
return a+b; }

test(5+2); // результат будет 7.
```

Тут принцип работы понятен, мы написали функцию с параметрами, потом просто вызвали ее. А первый пример я никак понять не могу.

Извините пожалуйста, за формулировку, в этом деле новичок.

Comment: внутри $.ajax эта функция вызывается с нужным параметром, результатом выполнения запроса.

Comment: Я не могу понять, что делает параметр data, для чего он.

Comment: _параметр data_ - **результат выполнения запроса**

Comment: В параметре data будет результат выполнения успешного запроса.

Comment: Разберитесь чем формальные параметры от фактических отличаются.

Comment: data - это ничто иное, как xhr.responseText

Answer (score 3):

Для начала посмотрим функции.

Имеются:

```
function(data) {
    $('.results').html(data);
}
```

и

```
function test(a, b) {
    return a+b; 
}
```

Обе показывают, что они принимают некие параметры. Одна два параметра (`a` и `b`), переданные через вызов по имени непосредственно: `test(3, 2)`, другая — один параметр `data`, переданный откуда-то. Откуда она берется?

Что такое `$.ajax`? Во-первых — это всего лишь обертка над стандартным **[XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)**, который дает возможность из *JavaScript* делать HTTP-запросы к серверу без перезагрузки страницы. Этот самый запрос принимает с сервера данные. Примитивный пример:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'test.php', false);
xhr.send();

// Вот тут принимается ответ
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  // если ошибка то что-то сделать
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {  
  xhr.responseText // <!---- А ВОТ ЭТО ОТВЕТ СЕРВЕРА
}
```

Как видим в переменной `responseText` лежит ответ, который нам прилетел в ответ на запрос. Вот он то и отдается в виде аргумента в функцию.

Если схематично и **утрированно** изобразить `$.ajax`, то получится:

```
var ajax = {
    xhr: null,
    prepare: function(url) {
        // Получение объекта XMLHttpRequest
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        this.send();
    },
    send: function() {
        // Отправка данных
        this.xhr.send();
        // Получение данных
        var seldXhr = this.xhr;
        seldXhr .onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (seldXhr.status == 200) {  
                // при удаче вызываем success
                this.success(); 
            }
        }
    },
    // success принимает в себя callback-функцию,  
    // (то есть функцию, которую вызовем после каких-либо операций/групп операций)
    // которая И ПЕРЕДАЕТ ТОТ САМЫЙ АРГУМЕНТ в функцию
    success: funtion(callback) {
        callback(this.xhr.responseText); // <!--- Вот тот вызов функции и передача аргумента!!!
    }
}
```

Опять же схематично, да утрированно — этот самый `callback(xhr.responseText);` равнозначен тому самому вызову функции test: `test(3, 2)`, где `xhr.responseText` и есть та самая `data`.

Answer (score 2):

data - данные которые получены от сервера при успешном запросе http status = 200, он может содержать как html, json или любые данные которые отдаст сервер

Comment: Спасибо, для меня Ваш ответ пока самый внятный

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript**

```
...
$.ajax({
  url: 'ku.php?action=How are you?',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // I am fine thanks
  }
});
```

**php** (ku.php)

```
...
    if ($_GET['action'] === 'How are you?') {
       echo 'I am fine thanks';
    }
...
```

> Как работает этот параметр data?

Простой пример:

```
function tt(wow, callback) {
    if (wow === 'wow') {
        callback(wow);
    }
}

tt('wow', function(w){
    console.log(w);
});
```

Я как понял, ты об этом спрашивал.

Answer (score 2):

Что-бы понимать что такое `data` и как работает `success`, нужно понимать что такое [AJAX](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro) в принципе.
И как только разберешься с этим, сразу станет ясно, что data - это ничто иное как `xhr.responseText`, а работу `success` можно представить так:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        success(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что JQuery - это всего лишь библиотека, и разобраться как она работает без знания нативного JS будет трудновато.

Answer (score 0):

> перед тем как вызвать функцию

Вот, здесь главная ошибка в понимании, как оно все работает. Мы не вызываем обработчик `success`, а передаем определение нашей функции

```
function(data) { $('.results').html(data); }
```

(среди прочих опций) в функцию `$.ajax`. Вызывается эта наша анонимная функция кодом jQuery, и параметр готовит и передает в нее тот же (библиотечный) код.

Comment: вопрос был про `data` в том числе. ТС не понимает откуда оно

Comment: Алексей Шиманский  именно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как раз дописывал. все равно я считаю, что ключевой момент в процитированной фразе

Comment: @Igor объясните пожалуйста, более популярно. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @Алекс Давайте разбираться. Разница между определением функции и ее вызовом Вам понятна?

Comment: @Igor Да. Меня смущает именно параметр data.

Comment: @Алекс Мы вызвали `$.ajax`, передав ему набор параметров: строку `url`, куда будет послан запрос, функцию `success`, которая будет вызвана, когда ответ на запрос успешно вернется с сервера в браузер, и возможно - другие.

Comment: @Алекс Вот jQuery получил ответ, обработал его каким-то образом (не будем сейчас на этом задерживаться) и смотрит, так, у меня есть ссылка на функцию, которую программист хотел вызвать в случае успешного ответа. Вот и вызовем ее, а параметром подадим данные, пришедшие в ответе.

Comment: @Алекс "Вот и вызовем ее, ..." - это думает код jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

1. `callback` вызовет `jQuery` и передаст аргументом обработанный ответ, статус и `jqXHR` (обёртка над встроенным `XMLHttpRequest`).
   [Почитать](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81).
2. Подобный вызов вернёт `NaN` - в функцию пойдёт `a = 7, b = undefined`, а сложение с `undefined` к хорошему не приведёт, только к `NaN`.

Comment: 80% с написанного я не понял... Документацию по ВАшей ссылке уже читал. Если можно объясните более популярно

Comment: @Алекс, тогда скажите что Вам непонятно. Просто с моей стороны всё очевидно.

Comment: я не понимаю, что хранится в параметре data, что в него передается. Это какой то дефолтный параметр JQoery?

Comment: @Алекс Нет, это те данные, которые код jQuery получил в ответ на запрос к `'response.php?action=sample1'`

Comment: @Алекс, Вы же читали доку: "... Ей будут переданы три параметра: данные, присланные сервером и уже прошедшие предварительную обработку ...".

Comment: @Алекс Так вы изучить что такое делегаты или функция обра́тного вызова. Это передача метода по ссылке.

Comment: ссылка не рабочая